# How to play audiotracks in asp.net core mvc using javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I want to play audio tracks in my net core application. I've already tested similar code in sample html page with js script, it works.

```html
    <div><button onclick="playTrackStrFld('/Audio/track.mp3')">Play 1</button> 
    </div>
```

```
function playTrackStrFld(path) {
    var audio = new Audio(path);
    audio.play();
}
```

But if I try the same in a real app like this:

Controller method:

````cs
public IActionResult PlayTrack()
{
    string path = @"C:\Users\User\source\repos\WebApplication1\Essential\Audio";
    string audioPath = "/Audio/";
    List<string> musicFiles = new List<string>();
    string[] mp3Files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.mp3", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (var item in mp3Files)
    {
        string name = audioPath + Path.GetFileName(item);
        musicFiles.Add(name);
    }
    return View(musicFiles);
}

View:

    @model IEnumerable<string>
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "PlayTrack";
    }

    <div>
        <h3>@ViewData["Tracks"]</h3>
        @foreach (string musicFile in Model)
        {
            <p>
                @musicFile

                <button onclick="playMusic('@musicFile')">Play</button>
            </p>
        }
    </div>

javascript:

``` javascript
function playMusic(musicFile) {
    let audio = new Audio(musicFile);
    audio.play();
}
````

Nothing works!
Browser console says:

> HTTP load failed with status 404. Load of media resource >https://localhost:5001/Audio/BONES%20-%20HDMI-256.mp3 failed.

app console says:

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>        Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/Audio/BONES - HDMI-256.mp3
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 0.257ms 404

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `C:\Users\User\source\repos\WebApplication1\Essential\Audio` – You can’t use some internal path there. The path has to be something that is served through your web application so it can be accessed from the outside. For example, put the files somewhere into the `wwwroot` folder.

Comment: Is this after publishing to another machine? What does your directory tree look like for the app? `SolutionName\ProjectName\Audio\AudioFiles?`

Comment: You are using external path which you can't access. You should use `_env.WebRootPath` and check that works or not

Comment: Are you invoking `app.UseStaticFiles()` in `Configure` method